# How can I check that a remote computer is online for ssh / script access?

Tags: ssh, networking, scripting, backup, ping

I'm writing a script that will backup data from my laptop to an Ubuntu server.
To do so, I'm looking for a (ba)sh command to test if the server is available before starting the backup. something like `ping` on port 22 that returns a boolean.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this:

```
nc -z hostname 22 > /dev/null
echo $?
```

If it's `0` then it's available. If it's `1` then it's not.

Comment: Note that this option works only with the netcat-openbsd package, otherwise the option is not present: `nc: invalid option -- 'z'`

Comment: without `-w` option nc will be stuck forever on Ubuntu

Comment: can we have a similar command from windows

Comment: This tests if port $host:22 is open, not if a sshd is taking requests, which means a false positive on any/all proxied requests. Just timeout ssh if you want a valid/reliable check `timeout1 ssh blah` or `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 blah`

Comment: In my case the `nc` cmd was still outputting, have to use `&> /dev/null` to silence it.

Answer (score 16):

Use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/):

```
nc -z localhost 22
```

From the manpage

```
 -z      Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons,
         without sending any data to them.
```

Comment: Damn! You beat me to it.

Comment: thanks, didn't know nc , i was wondering why `nc -z -w 2 192.168.0.123` ( -w is the timeout option, in seconds ) does not timeout :|

Comment: You need to specify a port too. nc -z -w 2 192.168.0.123 22 works as expected.

Comment: +1 for the `z` into. whoever you scan still can get info of who did the scan only without providing the `identification string`

Answer (score 7):

Alternate:

```
nc -vzw 1 hostname 22
```

Comment: this should be selected answer, without `-w` option `nc` will be stuck forever on Ubuntu

Comment: Bool can be used like => `nc -zw 2 examplehost.com 22 && { echo "You can call your backup function" ; } || { echo "SSH Unavailable" ; }`

Comment: It's a very fine use of netcat .. however beware that not all ssh servers listen on port 22, and this may be reflected in the local /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
MACHINE=192.168.0.8
exec 3>/dev/tcp/${MACHINE}/22
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "SSH up"
else
    echo "SSH down"
fi
```

Comment: Don't always assume that it's Linux. His laptop may be a Mac. And Debian disables `/dev/tcp`. Ubuntu being Debian derived may as well (but I have no specific knowledge). But if `/dev/tcp` is available, then yes this is perfectly valid.

Comment: thx for your feedback, i've wrote it on a Mac.

Comment: thanks, even if `exec 3>/dev/tcp/${HOST}/22` looks really "bizarre"

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't require to install additional packages.

Comment: Works great for my use case in Mac and Manjaro (Arch Linux)

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh hostname exit 2>/dev/null ; echo $?
```

This actually creates a connection and performs authentication.
Also it does not rely on the port 22 assumption which is sometimes false.

Answer (score 0):

I improved Steveas answer by adding a timeout (here 2 secs):

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 -p <port> <hostname> exit 2>/dev/null ; echo $?
```

If port is the default 22 then you can run just:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 <hostname> exit 2>/dev/null ; echo $?
```

Without timeout `ssh` may wait a long time.

Using `ssh` instead of `nc` has a big advantage: It checks that answering daemon is ssh and not just any daemon. Successful "ssh ping" with `ssh` most likely indicates that the real ssh connection will succeed.

NOTE also that there is available app called `ssh-ping`. It is part of [ssh-tools](https://github.com/vaporup/ssh-tools)